# retrieving data from fusion table

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I have this google fusion table that has columns, `"date"`, `"name"` and `"origin"`. I want to retrieve the data under the `"date"` column so that I can manipulate other data such as `"name"` and `"origin"` and display it on my webpage. I have this algorithm in mind but I don't know the correct syntax, can someone help me on this?

my algorithm is this:

```
Select column "date" from my fusion table;
then there should be a for loop to search the data under this column;
if(a specific date has been found)
{
    then display the "name" and "origin" data that falls 
    unto this date
}
```

since I am new to javascript, Can someone make this into a correct javascript syntax or a code script snippet. Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

I got already this code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Fusion Tables API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <script>
    function handler(response) {
      var contentStr = "<table>";
      for (var i = 0; i < response.rows.length; i++) {
        var item = response.rows[i];
        contentStr += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < item.length; j++) {
          contentStr += "<td>" + item[j]+"</td>";
        }
        contentStr += "</tr>";
      }
      contentStr += "</table>";
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = contentStr;
    }
    </script>
 <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20destination%2C%20departure%20FROM%201fbsgSzpi7TRoyHAVFN82JwsaU5tjfB0akJmAapRm&key=AIzaSyB9lGkRr185Oen4WlR7gTYxzFYoNQ0cfSk&callback=handler"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

What it does is just display the fusion table. How will I costumize the query? I mean if only I know how to put the query url to a function so that I can change the filter gradually like i'll put it in a for loop and filter specific dates. Anyone?

Comment: define "display"(in a FusionTablesLayer or somewhere else) and "specific date" ...do you want to get only rows with a particular date ?

Comment: yes I want to get only rows with a particular date.

Answer (score 0):

the query is a simple SQL-query:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTableId where date='value'
```

You'll find the docs at https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/sql-reference#Select

when the `date`-column has the type DATETIME you'll find some possible options for the formatting of `value` inside the docs.

Comment: yep thanx. I would be pleased if you can provide me a function or a code snippet of it including how to connect to my fusion table. thanx

Comment: There is no unique snippet, it depends on the access-settings for the table. https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#auth